# Using Python to 're.split' unicode characters

Tags: python, regex, unicode, compiler-errors

I am attempting to split the following data field into 3 fields (pre, match, and suf) and input them into a comma-delimited txt file. I am reading all this in from a csv file...and it is utf-8 data.

My problem right now is that I can't get around the "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found" errors...however, seeing that I've tried to set my encodings, I don't know where the foul-up is here...

Sample data:

```
 A-1 طس
 TX 35-L
 Av Rib
```

Splitting on this should (\d+(-?[NSEW])?)supply me with this:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
A       |1        |طس
TX      |35       |-L
Av Rib  |         |
```

My current code is this:

```
## Iterate over csv file to create matches and splits 
## string according to regex pattern..

    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    with codecs.open(r'file.txt', 'w', 'utf-8') as outfile1:
        for row in reader:
           unicode_row = [x.decode('utf-8') for x in row]
           item = unicode_row[1]
           parsed = re.compile("\d+(-?[NSEW])?", re.UNICODE).split(unicode(item, 'utf-8'))
           outfile1.write(parsed + "\n")
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get TypeError? Is csvfile opened with `codecs.open` or just `open`?

Comment: is it a Python3 or Python2 question?

Comment: Using 2.7, I am opening the csvfile for read using just 'open' (but as you can see the write file is using codecs).

Comment: Playing with the encoding doesn't do much... I get the same error for : l = re.compile(ur'(?u)\d+(-?[NSEW])?', re.UNICODE).split(unicode(item, 'utf-8')) & outfile1.write(u'l' + "\n")

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because `parsed` is a list of lists.

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects